# Number as sum of multiples of 3 and 5.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> There were 10 questions on a test. A student gets 5 points for every correct answer and 3 points for every partially correct answer. If the student got 19 points, how many correct and partial answers did they have?

To solve the problem I express the total number of points as the sum of multiples of 5 and 3.

> 5x+3y=19

After that, the only thing I can do is find the solution by brute forcing it. Is there a more mathematical way of finding it?

Comment: This is a linear Diophantine equations with two unknowns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see that $19 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$, so we must also have $3y \equiv 4 \pmod 5$.  We check that the multiplicative inverse of $3$ modulo $5$ is $2$ (since $2 \times 3=6 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$), so we have $2 \times 3y \equiv 2 \times 4 \pmod 5$, i.e., $y \equiv 3 \pmod 5$.

Since $0 \leq y \leq \lfloor 19/3 \rfloor=6$ (along with satisfying $y \equiv 3 \pmod 5$) we must have $y=3$ and hence $5x+3y=19$ implies $x=2$.

This gives the unique non-negative integer solution $(x,y)=(2,3)$.

(Note that the uniqueness of the solution is mainly because "19 is small".  E.g. if the equation were $5x+3y=34$ there would be more than one solution.)

Comment: Arn't there 2 equations $5x+3y=19$ and $x+y=10$. If I solve them I don't get integer values for $x,y$ x being correct answers and y partially correct answers?

Comment: x+y=10 is wrong because not all of the questions were answered, as shown by the result.

Comment: Adding in $x+y=10$ is equivalent to saying every answer is at least partially correct.  (Omitting it allows the possibility that some answers were wrong.)

Comment: Why do we have the $3y \equiv 4 \pmod 5$? What makes it true?

Comment: We take the equation $5x+3y=19$ modulo $5$.

Comment: And then? I'm terribly sorry for asking so many questions, but I don't understand that part at all.

Comment: Since $x$ is an integer, we know $5x \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.  We compute $19 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$.  So we're left with $3y \equiv 4 \pmod 5$.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

$5x + 3y = 19$. So $5x \leq 19$, thus $x \leq 3$. Check $x = 2$, and $y = 3$ is the only integer values solution.